# cooperative game, a positive reward for null player

Tags: vectors, game-theory

I wonder how [here](https://www.uv.es/ecalvo/Emilio%20Calvo_archivos/Research/Research%20in%20Game%20theory_archivos/IGTR-2013.pdf) on the page 8,
$$\Delta^{av}(S,v)$$ can be positive even in the case that $$\Delta^i(S,v)=0$$ are all zero.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've got the point. Even if $$\Delta^i(S,v)=0$$ are zero for a fixed $i$ and all $S$ then still it can be the case $$\Delta^{av}(S,v) > 0$$ simply because there are other players besides $i$ in $S$.